# When doing cross validation, what changes if you ensure that the class distribution in the training and test set is equal to the whole set?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cross-validation

Let's take a binary classification problem.

When doing k-fold cross validation, when you separate the randomly shuffled dataset into k chunks, how likely are they to have the same label distribution as a function of k?

If the class distribution is very uneven, say that 95% of the dataset are negatives and only 5% are positives, then it seems pretty likely that there are even some low values of k for which the label distribution will be uneven. 
This is of course true for values of k such as k = (size of dataset), but what about low values of k, such as 5.

My main fear is that it may occur that I don't have enough positive examples in the training set in some phase of cross validation.
On the other hand, if I go and ensure an equal label distribution in all chunks, it seems to me that I may be bringing bias into my problem.

Basically what I want to ask is, what do I gain and what do I lose, if I ensure that the label distribution is even in all chunks? Would this be good or bad? And most importantly, why?

Comment: Just curious, how many negatives and positives do you have (not percentages, but actual numbers)? Also, what metric (such as accuracy) are you using to judge the effectiveness of the algorithm (probably an SVM?).

Comment: let's say 100 positives and 3000 negatives; the metric is AUC, and yes it's an SVM

Comment: If you're using AUC, then I don't think that this imbalanced data should be too much of an issue. This only because a big issue if you're using accuracy as a metric, since a classifier that just classifies everything as negative will have a accuracy of 95%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems similar to the question here
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/why-use-stratified-cross-validation-why-does-this-not-damage-variance-related-b

Anyways, you'll have different models if you have 1% to 6% positives. Just better to build on a balanced data set.

How will there be a bias?

Comment: I thought there may be a danger of bias because by ensuring equal distributions, the process would not be truly random, because you would choose the exact sets of positives and negatives, on which you would then perform random sampling.